# Finding the most popular/active sites based on a topic

Tags: search

What's the best way to find the top sites based on a certain topic/category/interest? For example if I want to find the top few Apple sites that contain news/articles/reviews etc, can I find these in a list somewhere? This could be based on site traffic but possibly also user-curated. Alexa is too general. Google search is too detailed.

Comment: could i get some details about why this is off topic? My intent was to find a web site/web app that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this site today and it's more what I was looking for - http://www.allmyfaves.com
It has many different categories to browse. Anyone know of any other similar ones?

Comment: actually it's part of your list! LOL

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty good list I just came across:

[What are the most intellectually stimulating websites you know of?](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/tmtd4/what_are_the_most_intellectually_stimulating/c4o3csl)

Comment: that is an excellent list.. sort of random as it's just in a discussion forum though

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [StumbleUpon](http://www.stumbleupon.com)? It’s a really nice website that allows users to randomly browse/stumble upon websites on a particular topic/interest/area. Just sign up, add your interests and start stumbling! It has a large user base and the content is always fresh!

Comment: I've used SU for years (although not so much with Chrome due to poor toolbar support). It's great but more random than what I was looking for. See my answer for more what I was looking for. Thanks :)